# Unable to activate integration in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, integration

I have created an integration in Magento 2.0. But I am unable to activate it.It gives warning as "Integration 'xyz' has been sent for activation." Can anybody let me know how much time it takes to activate the integration?